# Android google map v2 doesn’t work after update

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I updated the google play services in my project today and after that when I run my project I see this warning in logcat.
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2653): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5077000 but found 4452038
and don't show google map.

Comment: Also .....update your Google Play Services

Comment: which api level u have in eclipse??